# How to search for Events on the Custom Search API?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

Does the custom search API allow for searching for events as you would the events page directly?

For example, this url:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=cool+conferences&oq=cool+conferences&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn#htivrt=events&htidocid=L2F1dGhvcml0eS9ob3Jpem9uL2NsdXN0ZXJlZF9ldmVudC8yMDIwLTA5LTI2fF8xNDQ0MTI3ODg0MDQ1NDM0NjM2Mg%3D%3D&fpstate=tldetail

But within the `customsearch/v1` API space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly--the customsearch API doesn't support the same specialized search interfaces that google.com does.

You might be able to get close by creating a search engine and adding a [Knowledge Graph restrict](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/9350760) to search pages on the entity "event" or "conference", or a more specific Knowledge Graph entity if you have one in mind: the more specific the entity, the better the results usually are.